# Oracle SQL: Refer to expression output from last record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a product sales source data as below.

```
Product     SalesDate

ProductA    28-Apr-2015
ProductA    28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015
```

Used LAG function to get prev sales date.

```
Product     SalesDate       PrevDate
ProductA    28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015
```

Used following logic to create a New date.

```
CASE WHEN Sales Date - Prev Sales Date <= 10 days THEN Prev Sales Date
ELSE Sales Date
END as New date
```

Output that I got is

```
Product     SalesDate       PrevDate        NewDate
ProductA    28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015
```

Here is the tricky part. I am expecting the New Date as 28-Apr-2015 in last 3 rows. To achieve this, LAG function in each row should refer to the New Date of previous row.

That means you have to refer to New Date (which is calculated expression) from previous row.

The desired output is as below.

```
Product     SalesDate       PrevDate        NewDate
ProductA    28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
ProductA    30-Apr-2015     30-Apr-2015     28-Apr-2015
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your Oracle version is at least 11g, you can use this [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL) query:

```
with t as (
  select product, salesdate, 
      row_number() over (partition by product order by salesdate) rn
    from products),
r(rn, product, salesdate, newdate) as (
  select rn, product, salesdate, salesdate newdate from t where rn = 1
  union all 
  select t.rn, t.product, t.salesdate,  
      case when t.salesdate - r.newdate <= 10 then r.newdate else t.salesdate end
    from r join t on r.product = t.product and r.rn + 1 = t.rn)
select * from r
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48b7d/1)

I added two more rows in demo to check date difference condition.